# Copy file using FileInfo and certificate keys for creditencials

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question, I want to copy a file to remote server using FileInfo, procedure looks quite easy:

```
var source = new FileInfo(path);
var target = string.Format(@"\\{0}{1}", IPAddress, path);

FileInfo copyToDut = source.CopyTo(target, true);
```

Now I'm stuck on a problem is it possible to copy this way using private and public key. I've looked but can not find any answers.

By certificates I mean network certification same keys you use for ssh connection for example that allows to connect without user name and password.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by 'copy using private and public key'?

Comment: are you talking about network credentials or are you copying a certificate?

Comment: Network certification same keys you use for ssh connection for example.